# getsentry.banno-tools.com showing on a blacklist?

Tags: blacklist, banno-digital-toolkit

we are having a couple of customers see false positives in regard to https://getsentry.banno-tools.com/api/2/security when they log into Banno, thus the client's may not get access w/o whitelisting the aforementioned Host/URL.  I suspect that the site/URL has made it to a blacklist somewhere, but at this time not sure where.

Comment: You'll have to ask your customers for more information about their environment.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.